# Optimization problem with multiple knapsack does not work correctly

Tags: python, optimization, knapsack-problem, or-tools

I am trying to solve a Multiple Knapsacks Problem in Python which consists on putting items in 5 bins and the constraint is that each bin(bag) must contains items with same cluster (so we must not find two object with different clusters in the same bin) and maximizing the sum  KPI of items packed in the bins

Here is the dataframe data:

```
index   Cluster PageId  OsId    BrowserId   Impressions VideoComplete   Clicks  VolumePred  KPIPred ConversionPred  pond
0          1    0      1016529     11          16           43            16         1       175.0     0.025703     1
1          2    0      1016529     11          17            1             1         0         4.0     0.100000     1
2         12    0      1068379     11          12            1             0         0         4.0     0.150000     1
3         21    0      1074581     11          16           82            36         2       334.0     0.024457     1
4         22    0      1074581     12          14            3             2         0        12.0     0.035648     1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
310     1392    9       955767     11          11          264           170        12      1076.0     0.056217     1
311     1396    9       955767     11          17           42            32         2       171.0     0.118330     1
312     1397    9       955767     12          12            7             1         2        29.0     0.234646     1
313     1398    9       955767     12          14           31            17         1       126.0     0.026832     1
314     1405    9       988119     11          16           66            49         1       269.0     0.019075     1
```

To solve it:

I created a first Assignment-matrix A : items <-> bins like this :

```
      item     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   
 bins
 0   
 1    
 2    
 3    
 4 
              <=1 <=1 <=1 ...................................      <=1 <=1 <=1 


data1 = {}
pond = data['pond']
Cluster = data['Cluster']
OsId = data['OsId']
BrowserId = data['BrowserId']
PageId = data['PageId']
volume = data['VolumePred']
conversion = data['ConversionPred']
KPI = data['KPIPred']

assert len(OsId) == len(BrowserId) == len(PageId) == len(conversion)

data1['Cluster']  = Cluster
data1['pond'] = pond
data1['OsId'] = OsId
data1['BrowserId'] = BrowserId
data1['PageId'] = PageId
data1['conversion'] = conversion
data1['volume'] = volume
data1['KPI'] = KPI
data1['items'] = list(range(len(BrowserId)))
data1['num_items'] = len(OsId)
number_bags = 5 #All have the same capacity of 50 pounds

data1['bag_capacities'] = [50,50,50,50,50]#pounds
data1['bag_PageId'] = [50,50,50,50,50] #while this equals bag_capacities, I made it its own variable in case
data1['conversion_capacities'] = [5,5,5,5,5]
#data1['bag_capacities'] = [50,50,50,50,50] #while this equals bag_capacities, I made it its own variable in case

#I wanted to change the OsId at a later data1
data1['bags'] = list(range(number_bags))

assert len(data1['bag_capacities']) == number_bags
assert len(data1['bag_capacities']) == len(data1['bag_PageId']) == len(data1['conversion_capacities'])
print("OsId: ",*data1['OsId'])
print('BrowserId:',*data1['BrowserId'])
print('PageId:',*data1['PageId'])
print('conversioniation Levels:', *data1['conversion'])
print("Number of Items:", data1['num_items'])
print("Number of Knapsacks:" , number_bags)
print('Knapsack Capacities: 50 Pounds, 50 cubic inches, 5 Levels of conversioniation')
```

**Variable 1**

```
#x[i,j] for item i in knapsack j
x = {}
for i in data1['items']:
    for j in data1['bags']:
        x[(i,j)] = solver.IntVar(0,1,'x_%i_%i' % (i, j))
```

Then, I add a second matrix : Assignment-matrix B item-classes <-> bins:

```
data2={}


unique_cluster = set(np.array(Cluster))

partition = [np.where(Cluster == i)[0] for i in unique_cluster]
data2['class'] = list(unique_cluster)
data2['bags'] = list(range(number_bags))

#x[i,j] for item i in knapsack j
x2 = {}
for i in data2['class']:
    for j in data2['bags']:
        x2[(i,j)] = solver.IntVar(0,1,'x_%i_%i' % (i, j))
```

Then, I precise the list of constraints:

```
#Constraint for an item being placed in 1 knapsack
for i in data1['items']:
    
    solver.Add(sum(x[i,j] for j in data1['bags'])<=1)
 
 #Knapsack Capacity Constraint
for j in data1['bags']:
   
    solver.Add(sum(x[(i,j)]*data1['pond'][i] 
                 for i in data1['items']) == 5)    
 
 #Constraint for a class of item is  being placed in 1 knapsack
for i in data2['class']:
    solver.Add(sum(x2[i,j] for j in data2['bags'])<=1)

A=np.where(Cluster == 0)[0].tolist()

for b in data1['bags']:
    for c in data2['class']:
        print(b,c)
        u=len(np.where(Cluster == c)[0].tolist())

        print(c,b)
        
        solver.Add(sum(x[z,b]
                       for z in np.where(Cluster == c)[0].tolist()) <= (x2[c,b]*u))
```

Then, I precise the optimization objective:

```
objective = solver.Objective()
for i in data1['items']:
    
    for j in data1['bags']:
        objective.SetCoefficient(x[(i,j)], data1['KPI'][i])
        
objective.SetMaximization()
```

**Resolution**

```
solv = solver.Solve()
if solv == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
    #print('Total Packed Value:', objective.Value())
    total = 0
    kpi_moyen = 0
    kpi=0
    total_conversion = 0
    nombre_impression = 5
    
    
    for j in data1['bags']:
        bag_value = 0
        bag_weight = 0
        bag_volume= 0
        bag_rad = 0
        bag_conversion=0
        max = 0
        i_max=0
     
      
       
        print('\n','Bag', j+1 , '\n')
        
        for i in data1['items']:
                    
           
            if((x[i,j].solution_value()>0)):
                print('OsId',data1['OsId'][i], 
                      'Cluster', data1['Cluster'][i],
                      'BrowserId', data1['BrowserId'][i], 
                      'PageId', data1['PageId'][i],
                      'conversion', data1['conversion'][i],
                      'volume', data1['volume'][i],
                      'KPI', data1['KPI'][i]
                     )
                bag_value += data1['volume'][i]
                print(bag_value)
                bag_weight += data1['KPI'][i]
                bag_conversion += data1['conversion'][i]
                
        print('Packed Knapsack Volume Value: ', bag_value)
        print('impression number', nombre_impression)
        print('Packed Knapsack KPI: ', bag_weight/nombre_impression)
        kpi = bag_weight/nombre_impression
        total= total+bag_value
        kpi_moyen = kpi_moyen+kpi
        total_conversion= total_conversion+bag_conversion
        
  
   
        
    print("#######################################################")
    print("#######################################################")
    print("#######################################################")
    
    
    print("Le volume total", total)   
    print("KPI Moyen", kpi_moyen/5)
    
    
    
else:
    print("There is no optimal solution")
```

And finally as result I get this five bins with their items:

```
> Bag 1 
> 
> OsId 11 Cluster 0 BrowserId 12 PageId 1149586 conversion 3.0 volume
> 4.0 KPI 0.6890546435965691
> 4.0 

OsId 99 Cluster 0 BrowserId 16 PageId 1154705 conversion 3.0 volume 8.0 KPI 0.3472222222222222
> 12.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 0 BrowserId 17 PageId 789615 conversion 3.0 volume 4.0 KPI 0.6564351851851853
> 16.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 0 BrowserId 11 PageId 955761 conversion 9.0 volume 37.0 KPI 0.2541666666666666
> 53.0 

OsId 99 Cluster 7 BrowserId 16 PageId 917224 conversion 4.0 volume 12.0 KPI 0.3292739040060469

> 65.0 Packed Knapsack Volume Value:  65.0 impression number 5 Packed Knapsack KPI:  0.45523052433533806
> 
>  Bag 2 
> 
> OsId 99 Cluster 12 BrowserId 16 PageId 941080 conversion 2.0 volume
> 4.0 KPI 0.5508680555555555
> 4.0 

OsId 12 Cluster 9 BrowserId 16 PageId 1018637 conversion 4.0 volume 12.0 KPI 0.321111111111111
> 16.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 9 BrowserId 17 PageId 1154705 conversion 13.0 volume 33.0 KPI 0.3886526452221044
> 49.0 

OsId 99 Cluster 9 BrowserId 12 PageId 955761 conversion 11.0 volume 33.0 KPI 0.3366657218442933
> 82.0 

OsId 12 Cluster 9 BrowserId 12 PageId 955767 conversion 7.0 volume 29.0 KPI 0.2346455795175744

> 111.0 Packed Knapsack Volume Value:  111.0 impression number 5 Packed Knapsack KPI:  0.3663886226501277
> 
>  Bag 3 
> 
> OsId 99 Cluster 4 BrowserId 16 PageId 1109643 conversion 1.0 volume
> 4.0 KPI 0.3055555555555556
> 4.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 4 BrowserId 11 PageId 1149586 conversion 6.0 volume 8.0 KPI 0.7676237922705315
> 12.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 4 BrowserId 15 PageId 1149586 conversion 8.0 volume 33.0 KPI 0.2383133975812547
> 45.0 

OsId 12 Cluster 4 BrowserId 16 PageId 1154705 conversion 10.0 volume 41.0 KPI 0.2528392857142857
> 86.0 

OsId 12 Cluster 4 BrowserId 14 PageId 955767 conversion 4.0 volume 20.0 KPI 0.2225
> 106.0 

Packed Knapsack Volume Value:  106.0 impression number 5 Packed Knapsack KPI:  0.35736640622432553
> 
>  Bag 4 
> 
> OsId 11 Cluster 15 BrowserId 17 PageId 1109643 conversion 5.0 volume
> 12.0 KPI 0.3877777777777778
> 12.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 15 BrowserId 17 PageId 1187774 conversion 3.0 volume 12.0 KPI 0.236237684729064
> 24.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 15 BrowserId 11 PageId 955765 conversion 10.0 volume 41.0 KPI 0.2319838228361533
> 65.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 18 BrowserId 17 PageId 1074581 conversion 5.0 volume 16.0 KPI 0.300344742063492
> 81.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 18 BrowserId 16 PageId 1148073 conversion 3.0 volume 4.0 KPI 0.6833333333333333

> 85.0 Packed Knapsack Volume Value:  85.0 impression number 5 Packed Knapsack KPI:  0.36793547214796407
> 
>  Bag 5 
> 
> OsId 11 Cluster 21 BrowserId 12 PageId 1016529 conversion 3.0 volume
> 8.0 KPI 0.3541076152683295
> 8.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 21 BrowserId 12 PageId 1068379 conversion 3.0 volume 4.0 KPI 0.6711734693877551
> 12.0 

OsId 12 Cluster 21 BrowserId 16 PageId 911433 conversion 5.0 volume 16.0 KPI 0.3160714285714284
> 28.0 

OsId 11 Cluster 21 BrowserId 12 PageId 941080 conversion 2.0 volume 8.0 KPI 0.2876372053872053
> 36.0 

OsId 12 Cluster 21 BrowserId 14 PageId 941080 conversion 2.0 volume 8.0 KPI 0.275
> 44.0
```

The problem is I found in the same bag or bin item with multiple cluster for example in bag 1 we found items with cluster 0 and 7.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: In your Knapsack Capacity Constraint shouldn't it be `<=5` instead of `==5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "constraint for a class of item is  being placed in 1 knapsack"

```
for i in data2['class']:
    solver.Add(sum(x2[i,j] for j in data2['bags'])<=1)
```

ensures that each class is placed into some knapsack. It does not ensure that each knapsack holds only one class.

I think you will have to add

```
# Only one class per knapsack Constraint
for j in data1['bags']:
    solver.Add(sum(x2[(i,j)] 
                 for i in data2['class']) <= 1)
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it works. I have another queston since you know the knapsack problem. my question : is there an automatic way to determine the number of bag. Here i precise is 5 . Thanks !

Comment: It looks like you are currently maximizing the KPI that you can place into the 5 bags. You could instead minimize the number of bags as an objective; you would then have to add a constraint like "at least n amount of KPI total" or "at least m objects total" since otherwise the optimal solution would obviously be 0 bags.

Comment: Hamkins  Happy new year! Thank you for your instructive response. But i have no idea how to write my objective : I would like to maximize the number of bags. Can you help me please? thanks !

Comment: You mean *minimize* the number of bags, don't you? What is your lower limit on the amount of KPI or number of items required to be put in the bags, e.g. "all the items defined have to go into a bag" or "at least 100 KPI have to be put into bags"?

Comment: Last question was directed @buddy.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. My object is to create as many much possible of bags with maximizing the KPI of each selected item.

Comment: I tryed using this manner but I got an error : `objective = solver.Objective()
for i in data1['config']:
    
    for j in data1['bags']:
        objective.SetCoefficient(x[(i,j)], data1['KPI'][i])
        #objective.SetCoefficient(x[(i,j)], data1['volume'][i])
        
objective.SetMaximization()

# Objective: minimize the number of bins used.
solver.Minimize(solver.Sum([data1[j] for j in data1['bags']]))`

Comment: @buddy, I suggest you post a new question, it's hard to see what you're doing here. Creating "as many bags as possible", i.e. maximizing the number of bags (bins) doesn't make sense, you could could have an infinite number of them, most of them empty. Maximizing the total KPI as an objective conflicts with also minimizing the number of bags. You'll have to constrain one of them to some limit to sensibly optimize the other.